# Cannot understand diffrences in model between SQLServer and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing Windows Forms application in C# with *Visual Studio Express 2012* (**VS**) and *SQLServer Express 2012* (**SQLServer**).

For begin of my project I used to make modification with *SQL Server Management Studio* (**MS**) then in **VS**: *update from DB* at diagram view.

But now appears some differences as:

- a table is present in my **VS** diagram but not in **MS** and works fine with *Linq*
- I renamed some tables and field in **MS**, updated for those are not working in **VS** and if I updated myself then some errors appears like `dbo.myNewTable not exists`

What I want:

1. first, all works in my **VS** point of view
2. have both **MS** and **VS** synchronized
3. understand :)

Context is:

- one machine with all programs above
- one DB on SQLServer (or maybe I'm not sure if **MS** don't show what I imagine is the truth)
- in the past there was 2 close copies of same DB (but pretty far in past)

**Solution:**

in **VS**

- with: `DATABASE_NAME` is my database name
- and: `MACHINE_NAME` is my own machine name, basically where is hosted SQLServer

`App.conf`

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="DATABASE_NAME_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MACHINE_NAME;initial catalog=DATABASE_NAME;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

compare to **MS**

- name of database is `MACHINE_NAME\SQLEXPRESS`

seen this difference:

- try to connect **VS** to `MACHINE_NAME\SQLEXPRESS` using graphical connection assistant: only `MACHINE_NAME` is purposed
- try to connect **MS** to `MACHINE_NAME` using connecting box, both connections are available

Then as it was supposed, there was 2 different databases.

But why **VS** does not purpose all possible connections ?

Comment: Do you have a more specific issue? It's not really clear what you're asking here. (not my downvote)

Comment: Management Studio's Object Explorer cache of SQL object metadata is ***very*** sticky. You have to manually force a refresh if you change the SQL metadata outside of the Object Explorer (*even* if it's in another Management Studio window, like a query). To force a refresh, right-click on a folder in the Object Explorer that is above/contains the objects that you have altered and select "Refresh". Or else, exit Management Studio and restart it.

Comment: @retailcoder: I can give you more specifics stuff, but what ?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: already done that many times without success.

Comment: If Linq can access a table, but MS doesn't show it even after you restart, then it sounds like you're not looking at the same databases (this is suprisingly common and easy to do).

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I would like so. (also I updated my context in question)

Comment: also, I choiced to delete Model in VS and rebuild it. But still linked to something else than I see in MS.

Comment: I would like to compare `SELECT * FROM sys.databases;` result from MS and VS. But that's another deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're connecting to different databases, like you made a copy of the original database somewhere along the way and are now using that copy from one end, but the original on the other. check the `DSN`s for both connections to be sure.

Comment: yes sounds like I'm connected at 2 different DB. But also , I can see also only one server which is my own developing computer. Anyway I like the idea of have maybe 2 copies. So, looks not.

Comment: edited mistake in question box. Do you know why Visual Studio does not purpose all connections to SQLServer ?